# Match parts of a query with trigram index

Tags: postgresql, search, trigram, textmatching

I have a table of `events` where each event has a `title` and `description`. Searches should search both columns:

> **title**: Dick(ens) and Jane
>   **description**: Meet weekly to discuss classic books!

Given the above, I would like a query of `book club` to match.

My index:

```
CREATE INDEX evsearch_idx on events using gist((title || ' ' || description) gist_trgm_ops)
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE title || ' ' || description ILIKE '%book club%'
```

I think the problem is that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how an index works and therefore it's attempting to match the entire string `book club` to various three-letter combinations but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe you want `SELECT * FROM events WHERE title || ' ' || description  SIMILAR TO '%(book|club)%'` [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e79d5a66a50c35458b9e9a245f8d297e)

Comment: If I search for `jane`, nothing is returned in this case. Do I need to use `ILIKE` for one word and `SIMILAR TO` when finding multiple?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM events WHERE title || ' ' || description  SIMILAR TO '%(Jane)%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ILIKE` will always try to match the whole string. For example, to match `ILIKE '%book club%'`, a string **needs** to include the whole string `book club`.

If you want to use the similarity matching potential of `pg_trm`, you need to use the matching operators for which it was designed. Taken from [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html):

1. `%` returns true if its arguments have a similarity that is greater than the current similarity threshold set by pg_trgm.similarity_threshold.
2. `<%` returns true if the similarity between the trigram set in the first argument and a continuous extent of an ordered trigram set in the second argument is greater than the current word similarity threshold set by pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold parameter.

**Side note #1**: Make it case insensitive by adding `lower(...)` in your index definition and in your queries.

**Side note #2**: `title || ' ' || description` will return `NULL` if `title` or `description` is NULL. If you want to guard against one of the 2 values being NULL, create the index on `COALESCE(title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(description, '')`

**Side note #3**: pg_trgm can only do so much. For really complex queries, you might want to look into [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html)